# How to quantify the spreadness of beam of air molecules as they escape from a capillary to a vacuum?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vacuum, flow

Consider a tube from an oxygen cylinder attached into a vacuum chamber. When the cylinder is opened, the molecules escape out into vacuum chamber. What makes the molecules spread out when they escape out of the capillary end? How to quantify the spreadness so occurred?

Answer (score 1):

See a vacuum chamber has no air inside it. So that is a low pressure region. But the capillary tube contains some pressure exerted by the air molecules on the walls of the tube. The fluid flows from a high pressure region to a low pressure region. So the air molecules spread out into the vacuum chamber filling the empty spaces. This continues as long until the pressure on both become equal.

Answer (score 1):

only if tenperatur is not 0K, any moleculus will move randomly ,it is so called thermal motion.
when all moleculus is in one close capacity, they move to herr and there, so what you see is they are always uniform, since you open the capacity, it is obvious that they will move out